# Linux Mint Hangs on Battery Check, Can't Access Terminal

Tags: startup, battery

freaking out a bit here.

Put in a lot of work tonight on a major paper that I cannot now access.

I was just about to go to bed and launched Minecraft for a 10 minute time of decompression and something caused the game to crash, so I reopened it and it hung at the loading screen.

I restarted the computer (hard restart) and Linux Mint went through the paces until it got to the point at which it does the battery check and it just hangs.

I looked up some solutions online and most tell me that I need to ctrl+alt+F1 to access terminal, but nothing I try can get me to access the terminal.

It's been so long since I've tinkered seriously with Linux I can't remember the setup well, I know that I have the OS on a SSD and the "data" drive on a SATA, so I imagine (from past experiences) if I can access the home/data drive through something like a bootable distro I can probably get what I need, but I would prefer to get Mint back up and running.

Any suggestions?

Thank you